# The view is not displaying returned data *LIST* from the controller ( PHP - JQUERY )

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, view, controller

I want to send a list **($data = ["1","2"];)** to the controller from the view, and the result (1 2) be shown on the console,
but my code shows the code source of the view page! not the list $data

CHECK THE IMAGE:

[image: Result Here Check]

MY CODE :

**Controller:**

```
public function deliverySetup(){
      if(isset($_POST['request'])){
        $request = $_POST['request'];
          if($request == 'deliverySetup'){
            $data = ["1","2"];
             $this->view("control/hajar", $data);    
         }  
      }
    }
```

**View:**

```
function deliverySetup(){
    $.post('<?php echo URLROOT ?>' + 'Scan/deliverySetup', {request: 'deliverySetup'}, function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Not sure what `$this->view("control/hajar", $data);` does but it sounds like it returns a HTML view/page. You'd only want to return the data

Comment: if i return just $this->view($data); -- The console result **( <b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\...\app\libraries\Controller.class.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
View doesn't exist )**  **not working**